# Can't get MathJax math font size to stay same size relative to surrounding text

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, mathjax

### Problem

I'm using MathJax to render math on my page:

[image]

I would like the math font to be larger than the text surrounding it, as shown above. But for some reason **on mobile**, the math font scales with the resolution and becomes unreadably small. I'm using Chrome's developer tools to emulate a mobile view, but I can confirm it's the same on my Android phone:

[image]

### MCVE

I have a **minimal complete verifiable example** but it doesn't work on JSFiddle, OneCompiler, or a couple other ones I've tried. I think it's because they render the resulting page in an `<iframe>` that isn't affected by going mobile in Chrome's dev tools. It doesn't even go mobile on my phone, actually. I can provide a temporary reproduction on my own server [here](https://andrewcheong.com/articles/mcve)—or you'll have to copy/paste the code into a new .html file yourself:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MCVE</title>
    <script>
      MathJax = {
        tex: {
          inlineMath: [['$', '$']],
          displayMath: [['$$', '$$']],
        },
        chtml: {
          scale: 1.2,
        },
        svg: {
          scale: 1.2,
        }
      };
    </script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 23px;
        line-height: 1.75;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
Our purpose is to study a certain feature of quantum mechanics as seen through a hypothetical device—this apparatus . This device—modeled on a real device of course—has a strange behavior that gives rise to an interesting property we'd like to study. It's this: Once you prepare the device, i.e. put it in one of the situations $\ket{u}$, $\ket{d}$, $\ket{r}$, $\ket{l}$, $\ket{o}$, $\ket{i}$, if you then orient it on a different axis and take a reading, you'll get $+1$ half the time, and $-1$ the other half of the time—<em>despite setting up the same starting situation and re-orienting the device exactly the same way every time</em>. In other words, the measurement of the re-oriented situation appears to be non-deterministic. Let's create a new notation to depict this "re-oriented situation" so it's easier to talk about:
  </body>
</html>
```

### What I've tried

1. I've tried using an `!important` style to force math fonts to stay the same (relatively):

   ```
   mjx-math {
     font-size: 1.2em !important;
     font-size: 120% !important;
     font-size: 23px !important;
   }
   ```

   Not at the same time obviously—tried them one by one. I can see in Chrome's developer tools that the final style *is* applied, yet the behavior is the same.
2. Taking advice from [this Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/g/mathjax-users/c/5h-NNba8pN4), I tried configuring MathJax with `matchFontHeight` disabled:

   ```
   chtml: {
     scale: 1.2,
     matchFontHeight: false,
   },
   svg: {
     scale: 1.2,
     matchFontHeight: false,
   }
   ```
3. I've tried setting this `<meta>` tag:

   ```
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.9, maximum-scale=0.9">
   ```

I've tried several other things but didn't keep track of them / have forgotten.

There's [a long discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/564) that may potentially be related but I couldn't extract a solution from it.

Comment: If you can't reproduce it on jsfiddle etc, your own code is doing more than what your MCVE are doing: don't write new code. Take your real code, stick it in a new dir, and start removing things there, retesting at every removal to see if you've removed enough or not. And that includes things like removing build steps, removing configs, removing sections of package.json, etc. etc. The important part is the _reducing_: rewriting from scratch isn't going to let you find the problem in your own code.

Comment: I didn't rewrite anything from scratch. I removed around 500 lines of code—and if I save and load the reduced code, the problem reproduces, and you can do it too. I simply chose not to reduce a couple things in order for it to match the screenshots I posted—and also because they do affect text in their own way. As for why JSFiddle won't work, I believe it's because the `<iframe>` showing the result isn't switching to mobile device no matter how narrow you make the viewport. Anyway that is just an inconvenience. Like I said, saving my code in a .html file and opening it in mobile reproduces.

Comment: Fair - in that case, you might find glitch.com more useful to show off the problem, which gives a full, real domain to work with.

Comment: Cool platform, I had never heard of it. If I can reproduce there I will come back and edit my question and probably be able to make it much shorter. Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
` to the document `<head>` and see if that helps.

Comment: @DavideCervone - This did help. Strange, I thought I already tried this when I found similar in [this Google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/g/mathjax-users/c/v0hYt3pvf_8). But maybe I had other code interfering. I say "helped" not "fully resolved" because with this, the entire page's font size on mobile was basically doubled—and in that situation the MathJax was the relative size I wanted—but instead I would rather have had the page's font stayed the same and just the MathJax font to also stay the same size relative to that. Anyway, would you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Notice: This question has been totally rewritten. I was able to eliminate Google fonts, Markdown, everything besides MathJax.

Comment: Just to make sure, you did use `matchFontHeight`, not the `matchFontEight` that is listed in the code block in your number 2, right?

Comment: @DavideCervone - Thanks for catching that. I just retried with the correct spelling but alas, same issue.

Comment: A couple more things to try:  try setting `minScale: 1` in the `chtml` and `svg` sections.  I doubt it will help, but is worth a try.  Also, have you tried `tex-mml-svg.js` instead of `tex-mml-chtml.js`?  That has a different way of scaling the output that might work better.

Comment: @DavideCervone - Granted I hard-refreshed correctly between all trials and didn't goof anything else up, unfortunately neither `minScale` nor switching to svg (and trying `minScale` and `matchFontHeight` there) showed any difference—still super tiny scaled math. If you have any more suggestions, keep 'em coming! Thank you.

Comment: Were you viewing your example file here, or a more complicated setup from which this was extracted?  If the MathJax configuration was in a separate javascript file, for example, then hard-refreshing doesn't always load the new version in some browsers.

Comment: It's the MCVE in my question, so everything in one file and inline, but saved in my virtual hosting service, editing locally via SSH, opening via web URL / refreshing the page. I was also looking at it from both Chrome dev tools on my desktop in mobile mode as well as my actual phone.

Comment: If it would interest you to know, I was using Chrome everywhere, but I can also try Firefox and Safari if you think it's worth checking.

Comment: Chrome is the one I was thinking of that doesn't always reload cached files, even when "force-refreshing".  I have to manually clear the cache via the preferences pane, and sometimes even stop the browser and restart in order to get it to load the new versions of edited files at times.  I'd be interested in what Firefox does, as it doesn't seem to have those issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested in a comment to try adding

```html
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
```

to the document`<head>`, as these scaling issues often are related to how mobile devices scale the viewport in ways that can confuse MathJax.

> I say "helped" not "fully resolved" because with this, the entire page's font size on mobile was basically doubled

Maybe try

```html
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.5" name="viewport"/>
```

and see if that is better?

You can read more about this meta tag [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag).  There are some other options that you might try, like `minimum-witdth` or `maximum-width` instead of `initial-width`, or setting `width` to a specific size.  I haven't worked with these much, so don't know which might work best in your situation.

Comment: Thanks! Moving my comments here as well. My findings after playing around with the `<meta>` tag: (1) Your suggestion worked! But with a side-effect. The math now stays a fixed size, as does the text surrounding. But overall it increased the size of everything. I notice though that the text on my mobile device looks almost exactly the size of the text on my desktop monitors—that could be coincidence, or exactly what this `initial-scale=1` aims to achieve. (2) As per your second suggestion, through trial and error I found `initial-scale=0.76` makes all the text the size that they were without

Comment: the `<meta>` tag. I bet that varies according to device. But still, it was possible to zoom out and the math would become miniscule again. (3) So, in the end I went with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=0.76,initial-scale=0.76,maximum-scale=0.76">`. It's the size I want the text to be on mobile (and hopefully close enough on other mobile devices), and it disallows zooming, effectively taking care of the shrinking math. I suppose that's not great for accessibility but I hope the font size I've chosen will be readable enough to most.

Comment: Incidentally, I found that Medium does the same for their articles: `<meta data-rh="true" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">`.